# Play audio file from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-connect

From my flow I can't play audio files stored in S3.
The playback function from a text file is working correctly.
The ability to play an audio file from the standard library is also broken.

but i want to play my custom WAV files stored in S3.
and it doesn't work or I don't know how to do it !!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Connect has updated contact flows to now allow playing a prompt from S3, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/play.html